# Any suggestions for list of supported streaming audio/video server?

Tags: software-recommendation, streaming

Any suggestions for list of ubuntu supported  streaming server;

I looked at some like

1. zeya
2. red5
3. gstreamer
4. ffmpeg
5. icecast-server / icecast2

I wanted know list of all robust or lightweight multi-user streaming server for video and audio.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about Flumotion. I haven't tried it myself, but I did read the documentation for it, and it seems like a really nice and professional solution. You can read about it here: http://www.flumotion.net/

Answer (score 0):

try [GNUMP3d](http://www.gnu.org/s/gnump3d/)... it has a web based UI which has list of files ready for streaming..!!